# How to optimize this bash function?

Tags: regex, bash, performance

I have made a bash function that would separate the image files that are larger than a certain size but I have around 20000 files and it's taking too much time and it doesn't utilize the CPU much at all so I was wondering maybe it was possible to optimize it a little without real complicated multi-processing(I don't mind multi-processing but I don't want to write 20 lines of code for such a simple task)

**Here is my code:**

```
getpics() {
    dir="larger than $1x$2"
    mkdir "$dir"
    for f in `ls *`; do  
        a=`file "$f" | grep -Po ", \K[\d]*x[\d]*"`
        x=`grep -Po "\d*(?=x)" <<< "$a"`
        y=`grep -Po "x\K\d*" <<< "$a"`
        echo "$a _______________________ $x, $y"
        if [ $x -gt $1 ] && [ $y -gt $2 ] ; then
            mv "$f" "$dir/$f"
        fi  
    done
}
```

Comment: Don't parse `ls` output . Read [\[ this \]](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: It's slow because you're calling external `file` and 3x `grep` for each file. Perhaps some of the `imagemagick` tools might be useful (and faster) here.

Comment: Provide some examples of your original and new file names.

Comment: @randomir I tried to do it with image magic but I couldn't find anyway to do it without the 3 greps. all I could do with imagemagick is the same as what I can do with file(almost)

Comment: @anubhava as you can see in the code original and new files have the same name which is basically something like: `other_1999_990801_world_005871.jpg`

Comment: Get rid of as many of the non-bash external programs as you can, like `ls` and `grep`.   You probably don't need `file`, but you will need `mv`.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: By the way, not sure why you mentioned threading, `bash` does not support user multi-threading.

Comment: Maybe you could enlighten me by showing me how I can get rid of `grep`.  I believe getting rid of ls would make any difference because it doesn't take any more than a third of a second in my computer. How ever globing seems to be a faster anyway.

Comment: @cdarke I'm sorry I meant multi processing.

Comment: `grep` creates a child process, bear in mind that your create, run, and destroy those child processes on *every iteration*.  3 child processes on 20000 iterations is 60000 external child processes!  Bash supports regular expressions, you don't have to use globbing.

Comment: @cdarke I don't see why you are not posting an answer! I'm sure you can make a great one!

Comment: I can't help wonder if `find` using `-size` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @cdarke You are suggesting that I choose my files based on their size on disk instead of the width and height?

Comment: @cdarke I can't help wonder why  you are not just posting a great answer and posing well informative improving comments everywhere instead:)) I just want to give you some rep that you deserve:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First lets do some benchmarks:**

**We start with the if:**

```
$ time for i in `seq 1 100000`; do if [ 2 -gt 1 ] && [ 3 -gt 2 ]; then a=1; fi; done

real    0m0.694s
user    0m0.693s
sys 0m0.003s

$ time for i in `seq 1 100000`; do if [[ 2 -gt 1 && 3 -gt 2 ]]; then a=1; fi; done

real    0m0.428s
user    0m0.424s
sys 0m0.006s

$ time for i in `seq 1 100000`; do if (( 2 > 1 && 3 > 2 )); then a=1; fi; done

real    0m0.366s
user    0m0.364s
sys 0m0.003s

$ time for i in `seq 1 100000`; do (( 2 > 1 && 3 > 2 )) && a=1; done

real    0m0.355s
user    0m0.352s
sys 0m0.005s
```

**Now let's look at `ls`**

```
$ time for i in `ls *`; do a=1; done

real    0m0.280s
user    0m0.249s
sys 0m0.036s

$ time for i in *; do a=1; done

real    0m0.128s
user    0m0.128s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Now some people might wonder if

```
desc=$(file "$f")
if [[ $desc =~ $re ]]; then
```

Would be different than

```
if [[ $(file "$f") =~ $re ]]; then
```

But there is no difference in the result. I also tested it so many times but each time one was randomly faster than the other. But I'm not putting the result of that here because I think it has no use.

Again you might wonder if there is a difference between

`^.* ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+),.*$` And `([0-9]+)x([0-9]+),`

But I tested it and there is none. However according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) The best regex (preserving the groupings) is:

```
.*, ([0-9]+)x([0-9]*)     : 33 steps.
, ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)       : 34 steps.
^.* ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+),.*$ : 38 steps.
```

Now lets compare different ways of getting `x` and `y`:

```
$ time (files=( * ); for f in "${files[@]:0:1000}"; do IFS=, a=(`file $f`);IFS=x b=(${a[8]});done;)

real    0m5.580s
user    0m1.147s
sys 0m4.498s

$ time (files=( * ); for f in "${files[@]:0:1000}"; do if [[ $(file "$f") =~ $re ]]; then x=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; y=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}; fi; done)

real    0m5.817s
user    0m1.234s
sys 0m4.619s

$ time (files=( * ); for f in "${files[@]:0:1000}"; do a=(`convert $f -print "%w %h\n" /dev/null`);done;)

real    0m10.356s
user    0m3.624s
sys 0m6.793s

$ time (files=( * ); for f in "${files[@]:0:1000}"; do a=$(file "$f" | grep -Po ", \K\d+x\d+"); IFS=x read x y <<<"$a"; done;)

real    0m12.645s
user    0m2.235s
sys 0m13.914s
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try avoiding calls to external tools as much as possible and using `bash` built-ins instead.

For example, to replace all `grep`s, you can use [`bash` ERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) (works in Bash 4+):

```
re='^.* ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+),.*$'
for f in *; do
    desc=$(file "$f")
    if [[ $desc =~ $re ]]; then
        x=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        y=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        # ... check size & move
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You must not parse output of `ls`
2. You can avoid 2 `grep` calls by using BASH regex (thanks to comments below and @randomir's answer)

Refactored script:

```
re=', ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)'
getpics() {
    dir="larger than $1x$2"
    mkdir "$dir"
    for f in *; do  
        if [[ $(file "$f") =~ $re ]]; then
           x=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
           y=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
           echo "$a _______________________ $x, $y"
           (( x > $1 && y > $2 )) && mv "$f" "$dir/$f"
        fi  
    done
}
```

Comment: Can't that `grep` be replaced by a bash RE?  Would `((  ))` be faster than `[[  ]]`?

Comment: @cdarke Why don't you just show how it can be removed? Maybe not everybody knows what you know! I can assume anubhava does tho:D

Comment: Is `[ $x -gt $1 ] && [ $y -gt $2 ]` slower than `[[ $x -gt $1 && $y -gt $2 ]]`?

Comment: @yukashimahuksay: probably, since `[` is a builtin (x2) and `[[` is a keyword.  However, it must be benchmarked to be sure.  My question was a question, not an answer.

Comment: @cdarke So you don't know any way to turn that `grep` into bash RE?

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why (()) is faster than [[]]?

Comment: @yukashimahuksay I suggest you test these changes and see if performance improves or not.

Comment: @anubhava are you sure your IFS solution is slower than bash RE?